# Why is useEffect called several times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I use hooks to set the values of a variable. I have a function that calls the API and sets the values of the "rooms" variable.

I used `useEffect` in order to do like `componentDidMount` lifecycle. However, even with the condition I put in my code, `getRooms()` is called up to 4 times in my application. When I render the values of rooms, I get 4 times the same room when it should be there only one time.

Here is my code:

```
export default function Rooms() {

    const [rooms, setRooms] = useState({})

    function getRooms() {
        client.get('/rooms').then((s) => {setRooms(s.data.rooms)}, (e) => {console.log(e)});
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(Object.values(rooms).length === 0) {
            getRooms();
        }
    })

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <InfoPanel
                title="rooms"
                description="skip this part if you don't have any room in your house"
                instruction="select and name every room you have" />
            <ActionPanel>
                {Object.values(rooms).map((r) => {
                    return <p>{r.title}</p>
                })}

            </ActionPanel>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

How can I make sure that my code is called only ONCE when the component mounts?

N.B: "client" is axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an empty array as a second argument for `useEffect()`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    doStuff();
}, []);
```

The second argument tells which changes should trigger the function. Empty array means that run it once, but don't react to furher changes.

See documentation right [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

Answer (score 1):

I optimized your solution

```
export default function Rooms() {

    const [rooms, setRooms] = useState({})



    useEffect(() => {
        function getRooms() {
        client.get('/rooms').then((s) => {return s.data.rooms}, (e) => {console.log(e)});
    }

        if(Object.values(rooms).length === 0) {
            const apiResult = getRooms();
            setState(apiResult);
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <InfoPanel
                title="rooms"
                description="skip this part if you don't have any room in your house"
                instruction="select and name every room you have" />
            <ActionPanel>
                {Object.values(rooms).map((r) => {
                    return <p>{r.title}</p>
                })}

            </ActionPanel>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```